# manage.py check fails upon connecting to local mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a brand new Django project. It only contains the bare minimum after a "django-admin startproject" call.

Everything is fine, but the moment I add my database settings to it, "python manage.py check" starts failing. To be more precised, it fails on "python manage.py check --tag models"

Here are my settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myschema',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysqlroot',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '33060',
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Please note that it seems that the issue only happens if the connection to the database is successful. If I put wrong information in the settings or if the server is not running, I will have the usual django error message.

Any idea? Ever saw something similar?

Is there at least a way I could debug at what level are going wrong?

EDIT: I've done

```
python -vv manage.py check --tag models
```

to try to get more debug info. The last lines look something like that:

```
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\Div-o\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\contenttypes\\__pycache__\\forms.cpython-                                                                                                                                  35.pyc'
import 'django.contrib.contenttypes.forms' #<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001A2447F6198>
import 'django.contrib.contenttypes.admin' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001A2447D8D68>
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyd
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.py
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyw
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyc
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyd
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.py
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyw
# trying C:\Users\Div-o\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\admin.pyc
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You may need to change the port to `3306`

Comment: I tried this and the issue was the same unfortunately

Comment: Check this from your command like `mysql -uroot -pmysqlroot myschema`

Comment: It says:

`mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

But PyCharm and MySQL workbench connect without issue

Comment: @ettanany Okay, it connected when i added `-P33060` to specify the port. But what now?

Comment: I can not see where this problem comes from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after days of pulling my hair I solved it by uninstalling my x64 version of Python and installing a 32 bit version instead.

I still have no idea what was wrong but that solved it. I did this cause that was the only thing that was different between the computer where my project worked and this one. If anybody knows why this could have caused trouble, I still would like to know why.